# How do I call via HTTPS in Laravel 5.1 PHPUnit tests?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5

In Laravel < 5.1, this was easy enough via `$this->callSecure()`. The documentation concerning the 5.1 "testing overhaul" is a bit sparse, though, and I can't find any reference to HTTPS calls.

I can't imagine it's simply not possible, but how does one make an (e.g.) `$this->post()` call use HTTPS instead of HTTP?

Thanks

Comment: as of Laravel 5.2 this functionality is back. you can say $this->callSecure($method, $uri)